# Anybody tried Intel® Euclid™ Development Kit

Tags: ros, realsense-camera, 3dcamera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a software engineer working mainly on robotic systems. I am wondering if anybody has tried the Intel 3D depth camera for robotic platform? How about its performance? From its description by Intel, it seems quite powerful and compact, I am considering to try this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268825/anybody-tried-intel%C2%AE-euclid%E2%84%A2-development-kit/) by [uvuvwevwevwe onyetenyevwe ugwemuhwem osas](https://answers.ros.org/users/31579/uvuvwevwevwe-onyetenyevwe-ugwemuhwem-osas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I received my Euclid this week and I'm trying to understand the Intel Euclid aproach now. Seems to be easy to extent some basic behaviors for students.

I've used an Intel NUC i5 (16 GB Memory, 256 GB SSD disk) with R200 before and I will give Euclid a first try now.

I did not expect too much, but simple SLAM with my Roomba should work. This Eucid box is really comfortable and easy to handle. I expect for small projects, it's enough power and better than using a Raspi and a lot of additional own build modules for IMU, CAM and other IO modules.

Cheers

Chrimo

---

Originally posted by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) with karma: 476 on 2017-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2017-08-28**:
Please keep us updated. I have looked at it but it's a lot of money for a hobbyist. Is it stereo camera or projector and camera like kinect? It's not obvious on the website but they say it can be used outdoors.

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2017-09-03**:
https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/2017/08/clearpath-robotics-announces-turtlebot-euclid/

I bet, this cooperation will give ros euclid users more informations for missing hw documentation and api.

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2017-09-03**:
Today, I'm tried the Euclid outdoors and I'm not very happy with the depth image...
Small trees or plants are not detected or shown.
Inside it is OK.
I need to check it without direct sun later.

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2017-09-05**:
https://discourse.ros.org/t/intel-euclid-irobot-explorer/2569

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2017-10-29**:
After 2 month of working with Euclid, I must say:
Software and SDK are OK and have nice UI, but the hardware is unusable for real robots.
Poor accu and charging capabilities, instable overheated board design and very poor ros support for new integrated sensors.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-29**:
Did it come with any 'promises' of 'ROS support' for the sensors?

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2017-11-11**:
no, still waiting for feedback... coming soon :-)